# blank page with no errors even in console

Tags: angular, typescript, angular10

I updated some packages and edited a few components but did not edited the routing or app-module.
Now i's only displaying a blank page.

When I start the application the application compiles successfully with no errors even in the developper console but it's not displaying any pages anymore.

Has anybody an idea on how to fix that ?

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';
import { HomePageComponent } from './home-page/home-page.component';

import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

// Firebase imports
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AngularFireStorage } from '@angular/fire/storage';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
//import { SearchBarComponent } from './shared/navbar/search-bar/search-bar.component';
import { AngularFireAuthGuard } from '@angular/fire/auth-guard';
import { NewCommentComponent } from './comments/new-comment/new-comment.component';
import { NewDocumentComponent } from './documents/new-document/new-document.component';
import { QuestionComponent } from './documents/question/question.component';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { SingleDocumentComponent } from './documents/single-document/single-document.component';
import { EditDocumentComponent } from './documents/edit-document/edit-document.component';
import { TemplateComponent } from './documents/template/template.component';

import { HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import { AngularFireFunctions, FUNCTIONS_REGION } from '@angular/fire/functions';
import { EditorModule } from '@tinymce/tinymce-angular';

import { CategoryDialogComponent } from './home-page/category-dialog/category-dialog.component';
import { DocumentCheckoutComponent } from './documents/document-checkout/document-checkout.component';

import { CarouselComponent } from './home-page/carousel/carousel.component';
import { ProPageComponent } from './pro-page/pro-page.component';
import { MarkdownEditorModule } from './markdown-editor/markdown-editor.module';
import { MarkdownEditorOptions } from './markdown-editor/markdownEditorOptions';
// import { CheckoutComponent } from './checkout/checkout.component';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import {MatStepperModule} from '@angular/material/stepper';
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
import {MatAutocompleteModule} from '@angular/material/autocomplete';

const editorConfig = new MarkdownEditorOptions();
editorConfig.autoDownloadFontAwesome = true;
editorConfig.initialValue = 'Hello Editor...write something amazing.';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomePageComponent,
   
    NewCommentComponent,
    NewDocumentComponent,
    QuestionComponent,
    SingleDocumentComponent,
    EditDocumentComponent,
    TemplateComponent,
    CategoryDialogComponent,
    DocumentCheckoutComponent,
    CarouselComponent,
    ProPageComponent,
    PanierComponent,
    MentionsComponent,
    // CheckoutComponent,
    
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    SharedModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    EditorModule,
    MarkdownEditorModule.forRoot(editorConfig),
    MatDialogModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule, 
  ],
  providers: [
    AngularFireAuthGuard,
    AngularFireStorage,
    AngularFireFunctions,
    { provide: FUNCTIONS_REGION, useValue: 'europe-west1'}
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { 
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "gdroit",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^10.2.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.2.7",
    "@angular/common": "^10.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "^10.2.5",
    "@angular/core": "^10.2.5",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.4.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^10.2.5",
    "@angular/material": "^10.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^10.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^10.2.5",
    "@angular/router": "^10.2.5",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^10.2.3",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.17.1",
    "@tinymce/tinymce-angular": "^4.2.4",
    "algoliasearch": "^4.10.5",
    "angular-instantsearch": "^2.3.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "firebase": "^7.24.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.15.5",
    "html-to-pdfmake": "^2.3.4",
    "html2canvas": "^1.3.2",
    "jspdf": "^2.3.1",
    "mammoth": "^1.4.18",
    "ng-image-slider": "^2.8.0",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^6.4.1",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^5.6.2",
    "ngx-clipboard": "^13.0.1",
    "ngx-owl-carousel-o": "^3.1.1",
    "nodemailer": "^6.6.3",
    "npm": "^6.14.15",
    "pdfmake": "^0.1.72",
    "stripe": "^8.174.0",
    "tinymce": "^5.9.1",
    "tslib": "^1.14.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "^0.900.7",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1002.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^10.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^10.2.5",
    "@angular/language-service": "^10.2.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.9.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.10",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.24",
    "@types/stripe-checkout": "^1.0.4",
    "@types/stripe-v3": "^3.1.25",
    "codelyzer": "^5.2.2",
    "firebase-tools": "^7.16.2",
    "fuzzy": "^0.1.3",
    "inquirer": "^6.2.2",
    "inquirer-autocomplete-prompt": "^1.4.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.7.0",
    "protractor": "^5.4.4",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.18.0",
    "typescript": "^4.0.8"
  }
}
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomePageComponent } from './home-page/home-page.component';
import { AngularFireAuthGuard } from '@angular/fire/auth-guard';
import { AdminGuard } from './guards/admin.guard';
import { ResetPasswordComponent } from './auth/reset-password/reset-password.component';
import { ProPageComponent } from './pro-page/pro-page.component';
import { CheckoutComponent } from './checkout/checkout.component';
import { PanierComponent } from './panier/panier.component';
import { MentionsComponent } from './mentions/mentions.component';



const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomePageComponent},
  { path: 'login', loadChildren: () => import('./auth/auth.module').then(m => m.AuthModule) },
  { path: 'cards', loadChildren: () => import('./cards/cards.module').then(m => m.CardsModule) },
  { path: 'collective-actions', loadChildren: () => import('./actions/actions.module').then(m => m.ActionsModule) },
  { path: 'users', loadChildren: () => import('./users/users.module').then(r => r.UsersModule)},
  { path: 'account', loadChildren: () => import('./account/account.module').then(m => m.AccountModule), canActivate: [AngularFireAuthGuard]},
  { path: 'admin', loadChildren: () => import('./admin/admin.module').then(m => m.AdminModule), canActivate: [AdminGuard]},
  { path: 'pro',component: ProPageComponent},
  { path: 'emploi', loadChildren: () => import('./emploi/emploi.module').then(m => m.EmploiModule)},
  { path: 'fiches', loadChildren: () => import('./fiches/fiches.module').then(m => m.FichesModule)},
  { path: 'checkout',component: CheckoutComponent},
  { path: 'panier',component: PanierComponent},
  { path: 'mentions',component: MentionsComponent},
  { path: 'auth/email/action', component: ResetPasswordComponent},
  { path: 'fiches', loadChildren: () => import('./fiches/fiches.module').then(m => m.FichesModule) },
  { path: 'emploi', loadChildren: () => import('./emploi/emploi.module').then(m => m.EmploiModule) }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { relativeLinkResolution: 'legacy' })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import{ Router } from  '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(
      private router: Router,
    ) {
      this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
        console.log(event);
      });
    }
  title = 'gdroit'
}
```

Comment: I would start to debug by injecting the `Router` in the constructor of the `AppComponent` and place some logs `router.events.subscribe(console.log);`. This logs all router events, check what component should render and investigate further. You also have `fiches` and `emploi` routes defined twice, you can remove a pair of those.

Comment: I dont know if I did it properly but it did not logged anything. 
PS : I've updated my question with edited files

Comment: Try to revert the package updates then. Update one at a time and check after each one if your app behaves as expected. Once you identify the problematic package, check the issues on github for any clues about which version is still compatible with the rest of your dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Trying adding a wild card route at the end of the routing module:

```
{ path: '**', component: HomePageComponent}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sadly it does not change anything

Answer (score -1):

[image]

In your **tsconfig.json** file Change the **target** to **es2017**...this works for me....i hope it works for you also...